# Simple LaTeX build and deployment combined with GitHub

Tags: git, github, latex, travis-ci

My personal homepage is under version control using a private GitHub repository and I am providing many sheets used during my courses there as well. For those sheets I have another private repository holding the LaTeX source files and thus far I have manually uploaded the pdf outputs to my server and registered them in the database. To automate this a bit I was considering to find solution to build and deploy the pdfs without the need to manually upload the files onto my server.

I stumbled upon the term of continuous integration and Travis-CI as a service which might help facilitate what I want. According to [this old ticket](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1235) there is no standalone LaTeX support but I read something about using an R environment which supports LaTeX. This is something I would have to experiment with to find out whether it works for my needs.

Assuming I manage to setup an environment which is able to compile my LaTeX sources (this will be rough since I might have trouble getting `latexmk` to work) what possible options do I have for deployment? At first I thought about uploading the generated pdf output to my private homepage using SFTP but this revolves around storing user credentials for SFTP into the config file which is then uploaded to GitHub. An alternative thought was to expose a script which can be called to receive the output file but this isn't safe either once someone gets the url.

Afterwards I read about Github Releases which would be a safer way to host my output files not fiddling around with uploading to my server. I would then just need a "crawler" on my site which fetches all available files under a certain tag or the newest release. However the caveat would be that files that I still haven't finished or files that should be available at a later date would be directly accessible. In my first scenario my registered files have assigned timestamps to them in the database to prevent download before a certain time (used for solutions to homework and such).

With these thoughts in mind I would like to ask you whether Travis-CI in this case is way too much over-engineering and/or whether there are more suitable solutions for my particular needs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic. It is probably better suited for Super User or Unix/Linux.

Comment: @RolandSmith I see your point - but why vote for closing it instead of migrating it over to Super User? Any particular reason? (And to be honest I struggled as well while thinking about where to post it.)

Comment: I voted to migrate it. Only a moderator can migrate directly.

Answer (score 1):

We use Travis to built a site based on Jekyll, we deploy to Amazon S3 (using [s3_website](https://github.com/laurilehmijoki/s3_website), but there’s a [whole bunch of deployment options](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/) supported by Travis out of the box). I thought the solution a bit overkill, but now that we have been using it for a while I’m quite happy. If you just need a way to deploy the site safely, you may use [environment variables](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/) or [encryption keys](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/) to pass your secrets to Travis securely.

Comment: I just stumbled upon the environment variables - the documentation itself is stating that one should use those for sensitive information that is the same across all branches. Thanks for the hint on that one thus far.